# Is there anyway to register a click on an image, ignoring transparent pixels, in JavaScript? (like if they clicked on a circle, or a blob)

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, click

So I understand how to calculate if the user clicked inside a rectangle, but is there anyway to register a click on the canvas that is on top of a blob, but not inside the rectangle that defines the blob image? Like the image is a blob with the rest of it being transparent pixels, but I don't know how to (or if) JavaScript can recognize if they clicked inside it.

Comment: If it has its own `id` tag or a anhy other tag you can track it, writing a `.click` function based on it should do the trick.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? like I just started the file so i've only defined the image as a new Image(), and I'm not entirely sure what the id is, or if it has an id.

Comment: Try inspecting your avatar image above, it has structure like this : `<div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ujur.png?s=32&amp;g=1" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="bar-sm"></div>` It has its own class. Similarly, search for a tag in your blob and see if you can write an onclick for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do that, you need to be able to read the pixel data of your image.

The canvas element and its 2D and webgl contexts are the only web-APIs able to do that, but for it to work, **you must serve your image in a same-origin compliant way** (i.e, you can't do that with an image coming from an other server).

If you can fulfill this requirement, then it's relatively easy:

- draw your image on a canvas
- grab the pixels data
- in the mouse event handler, transform the coordinates so they are relative to the image's coords
- check if the pixel at that event's coord is transparent (`0`)

Here is a simple demo using a 2D context and a mousemove event, you can change it to be a click one too:

```js
onload = (evt) => { // wait for the resource to be fully loaded
  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  // we create a canvas element
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  // set the canvas the same size as the image
  const width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  const height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
  // the 2D context
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // we draw the image on the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  // we get the ImageData out of it
  const img_data = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height );
  // the pixel data is an Uint8Array as [r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a...]
  // since we only want transparency, we can make an Uint32Array of it
  // this way one pixel takes one slot
  const pixels = new Uint32Array( img_data.data.buffer );
  
  // now we can start listening to mouse events
  img.onmousemove = (evt) => {
    // get the current BoundingBox of our element
    const bbox = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    // transform the event's coords
    const { x, y } = getRelativeCoords( evt, bbox, width, height );
    // the index in our linear array
    const px_index = (y * width) + x;
    // if this pixel is transparent, then it would be 0
    const over_color = pixels[ px_index ] !== 0;
    img.classList.toggle( 'over-color', over_color );
  };
};

function getRelativeCoords( mouseevt, bbox, original_width, original_height ) {
  // the position relative to the element
  const elem_x = mouseevt.clientX - bbox.left;
  const elem_y = mouseevt.clientY - bbox.top;
  // the ratio by which the image is shrinked/stretched
  const ratio_x = original_width / bbox.width;
  const ratio_y = original_height / bbox.height;
  // the real position in the the image's data
  const x = Math.round(elem_x * ratio_x);
  const y = Math.round(elem_y * ratio_y);

  return { x, y };
}
```

```css
.over-color {
  cursor: pointer;
}
img { border: 1px solid; width: 300px }
```

```html
<img id="img"
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
  crossorigin>
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect! Thank you so much!